# for loop in dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
future_to_url = {executor.submit(getHotelURLs, url): url for url in cityURLs}
```

The above code is from an concurrent.futures example in https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

It seems to me that a `for` loop is used in a dictionary. I am wondering if there is a documentation about this?

Comment: [PEP 274 -- Dict Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), If you don't know about [List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), see this first.

Answer (score 1):

This is [dict](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) comprehensions.
You should view the doc of [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (it works similar to dict comprehension)